# Xcode Localization Update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, localization

So I have localized a storyboard in Xcode using Use Base Internationalization.

I went in and translated all the strings in the strings files. Yay. That took forever.

Now I added a new element in the base file of my storyboard. It has a label in it, with a string that I need to internationalize. I saved it, built it, etc. But that new element is nowhere to be found in my pretty strings files.

Please do not tell me that I now have to manually add ALL of my elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html) says:

> To resynchronize your strings files with new content from your user
>   interface documents, use the --generate-stings-file option of the
>   ibtool command to produce new strings files. Then, manually merge the
>   new files into your existing localized strings.

That's pretty lame, but there you go. You could use something like FileMerge to help you sort out the differences. (We have a set of scripts that read in the strings files and merges them that way; it's not too hard to write such a thing.)

Comment: That is about as lame as it gets. Time for some serious custom software......give me a few days - this cannot be that hard to do elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

Manually find the object ID in IB's inspector(under the class section).
Manually write those new element yourself.

Comment: more clever one, create new localised language that not necessary for your project then copy the new element to paste in your old languages file, after that, delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem like this.

1. Uncheck one by one the checkboxes of your Localization utilities panel.
2. Xcode will ask, Do you want to remove the English (language) localization for Main.storyboard?
3. there is another checkbox in the dialog, don't check it
4. click remove.
5. Again select your story board, and recheck each language
6. Xcode will say File already exist
7. Selecte Replace file
8. Xcode automatically regenerate the strings files from your updated UI and replace your file.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it's easier to keep track of all the strings in a separate spreadsheet, and then automagically generate the .strings files for each language from there.

You still have to keep track of the translation keys in 2 places (in xcode and in the spreadsheet), but then at least you don't have to edit or merge all your Localizable.strings files each time you want to add some strings.

See example Excel spreadsheet with VBA macro here:
http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/multilanguage.zip

Comment: Yes, agreed. This is part of what we do as well.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for Xcode 6 and his new [localization features](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) (that I hope will tackle this l10n update pain in the ass), we could theoretically automate these steps (never tried)

- Generate the new strings [`find`/`xargs genstrings` and `ibtool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html)
- [diff](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff), [patch](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?patch) both version of each files
- Delete the unneeded files

This [gist script](https://gist.github.com/ole/5007019) (not easy to pronounce:) seems usefull too (again not tested yet)

Answer (score 0):

I found another lame solution, but it is less lame than the one found in Xcode release notes; tick the Localization languages off, delete the file from disk and now tick on again. This will recreate the `.strings` files.

Comment: I do this too. Note though, that this still requires the developer to manually merge the previous file and the current file.

Comment: Yes, but this can easily be done with merge software and Git revision. Still lame.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider to keep your translations in one clean XML file and make this Maven Plugin generate your strings files during each build: https://github.com/hoereth/i18n-maven-plugin