# How to update/synchronize Localizated Files in XCode

Tags: xcode

I localized all the strings in my storyboard and in my Localizable.stings file. After that I made some updates to both base files. Is there any way to update them or "syncronize" them so the deleted labels go away, the new ones get added and the ones that didn't change stay normal?.

I researched and the only thing that I found was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869913/xcode-localization-update). The solution given there is really lame and it was asked and answered 6 years ago so... has something changed since then?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you’re doing is totally outmoded. You should not be maintaining your own strings files manually at all. On each generation, just choose Editor → Export For Localization, translate the xliff file, and import back in. All the strings files are updated for you.

Comment: Watch any recent WWDC video on internationalization or localization for details.

Comment: Yes, you can find it here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/404/ and here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/401